# Firebase functions reading/accessing remaining node information

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have create a trigger to monitor the path `/Messages/{pushId}/originalText`, so this should only trigger if a change occurs at that specific node and nowhere else.

What I would like to do is access the remaining Node data so for example how would I need the node date at the `/Messages/{pushId}/followers` which sits at the same level as `originalText`

Sample:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/Messages/{pushId}/originalText')
    .onWrite(event => {

    //how to access data at another node, for example 
    //important/Messages/{pushId}/followers

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/Messages/{pushId}/originalText')
.onWrite(event => {
    event.data.ref.parent.child('followers').once('value', data => {
        console.log('Your data: ' + data)
    })
})
```

I suggest you to take a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) it is really nice and you can find everything you want!

1. [onWrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite)'s documentations says that `.onWrite` returns a [DeltaSnaphsot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot)
2. `DeltaSnaphot`'s doc says that `DeltaSnaphot.ref()` returns a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference)
3. `Reference`'s documentation has every query method you need, in this case [once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once)

Comment: How do I get the values from event.data!?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I didn't know the information you asked me so I provided an explanation of how I found them so that you can understand how to use the documentation :)

Comment: Does this solved your issue? In that case please consider accepting it